# What is the fastest way to get count of missing value for Big Data in python or spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

I am processing several data tables which have more than 20 Million rows with 30+ columns.
Currently I am using python pyspark to count Null value and calculate missing rate.
But it takes 40 minutes for one column check. If there is any other better way to process it to make it faster, please let me know. Appreciate it.

My current code is:

```
variables = ['A', 'B', ....]
for variable in variables:
    column = pandas.read_sql_query('select %s from dbo.ORDERS' % (variable), con=cnxn)
    column_missing = column.filter(column[variable].isnull()).count()
    total = len(column)
    missing = len(column_missing)
```

Edited Code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
import numpy
import datetime
import time
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col

order_pk = pandas.read_sql_query('select %s from dbo.ORDERS' % ('ORDER_PK'), con=cnxn)
summary = order_pk.describe().filter(col('ORDER_PK') == "count")
summary.select(*((lit(rows)-col(c)).alias(c) for c in order_pk.columns)).show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-30285cf9f59e> in <module>()
----> 1 summary = order_pk.describe().filter(col('ORDER_PK') == "count")
      2 summary.select(*((lit(rows)-col(c)).alias(c) for c in order_pk.columns)).show()

c:\users\pcui\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\functions.py in _(col)
     40     def _(col):
     41         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
---> 42         jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
     43         return Column(jc)
     44     _.__name__ = name

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Comment: you should be able to do `column.isnull().sum()` rather than doing this for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to make connection in a loop it takes hell amount of time.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
rows = df.count()
summary = df.describe().filter(col(variable) == "count")
summary.select(*((lit(rows)-col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```

You can use this rather `column.isnull().sum()` since it takes long time.

Edit: Please use SQLAlchemy to query the database to get the count each variable. all at once is great choice.

Comment: Let me try. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks and please let me know if something goes wrong.

Comment: I got this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' Do you know why?

Comment: can you please update the question with full code that is responsible for the error also post error code. I need to see how you're using udf.

Comment: Hi sorry, one last time can you tell me

`order_pk = pandas.read_sql_query('select * from dbo.ORDERS' % , con=cnxn)`  instead one column query all the columns in a table and let me know the how much time it's taking and rows count.

Comment: I tried. It includes 39 columns and 36 million rows. It took 30 minutes and still not load to dataframe. Should I try other method? I just want to find a better performance missing value check method.

Comment: the whole time is consuming on querying and loading dataframe . it depends on your system memory. and you can just query for count using sqlalchemy and store into variable. `SELECT
    COUNT(*) as num
FROM
    db.table1
WHERE
    column_name IS NULL`

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: `column = pandas.read_sql_query('select COUNT(*) as count from dbo.ORDERS WHERE %s IS NULL' % (variable), con=cnxn)`

Comment: Sorry I am not able to use pyspark in my system as of now but I will get back as soon as possible.